# Mongodb Collection test007.customer is not sharded

Tags: mongodb

I have step up mongo db as a cluster.
I am using mongo 4.0.0

1 config node, 4 shardsrv nodes, and 1 mongos node

From the mongos node while connected with robot 3T

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "test007" } )
```

Output

```
/* 1 */
{
"ok" : 1.0,
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1533293758, 4),
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1533293758, 4),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" },
        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
    }
}
}
```

Followed by

```
use test007
sh.shardCollection("test007.customer", { "_id": "hashed" } )
```

Output

```
/* 1 */
{
"collectionsharded" : "test007.customer",
"collectionUUID" : UUID("448797e0-afdf-46b1-b2db-92d8e8ed2661"),
"ok" : 1.0,
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1533293909, 2),
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1533293909, 6),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" },
        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
    }
}
}
```

I then perform a check

```
db.customer.getShardDistribution()
```

Output

```
Collection test007.customer is not sharded.
```

When i ingest some content into the cluster i can see all content from all shard nodes.

```
sh.status()
```

Output

```
{  "_id" : "test007",  "primary" : "cluster1",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : BinData(4,"4IIk2Q3fSYO67QusUND2og=="),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
    test007.customer
        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
        unique: false
        balancing: true
        chunks:
            cluster1    2
        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } on : cluster1 Timestamp(1, 1) 
        { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : cluster1 Timestamp(1, 2)
```

Any idea why the sharding is not initialized properly ?